# How can I set up magento to work with free shipping over 500 and also a discount coupon for 10% with code?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-rules

Can I get some help in Magento?

I have an online store set up for a client where I have set up shipping free for anything over $500. This works well throughout the checkout process.

I have set up another coupon code that gives 10% discount to a coupon code DIS123

This works well by itself as well. But when I use this coupon code and the price on the cart is over $500 it doesn't work. Any advice?

When I put the coupon code, there is a dropdown to select "Free shipping" and I have to select No.

What is my best option to get this working?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Fast and dirty method is:

```
template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
```

Display freeshipping_freeshipping if and only if base grand total in Quote is more than 500$

Comment: Thanks Jake, but I need to let my client dictate this, any way of doing this using the shopping cart rules itself in magento?

Comment: You can check out Promotions -> Shopping cart price rules. You should create new rule and in Conditions you can set as many conditions as you want. Also in ACtions Free shipping is available. The thing is that discount is counted after subtotal. Means that you should create some specific rule that coupon code can be entered only if Shipping method is not freeshipping, if that is what you want. My magento is 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'Free shipping' shopping cart price rule to make sure that in actions 'Stop Further Rules Processing' is set to No, otherwise any other rules that may apply won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should activate the Free Shipping from the System > Configuration > Shipping Methods and fill all the required values for the Free Shipping and put the Minimum Order Amount $500, it will show the free shipping whenever the amount will be more than $500 and now, We have to create the Shopping cart price rule (because we have to create the coupon code) in actions tab 'Stop Further Rules Processing' is set to No, otherwise any other rules won't be applied. Hope it helps,

Thanks,